# Moving a partition using GParted in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, udisks

I am trying to merge to non-adjacent partitions in Ubuntu using GParted. 
In the provided screenshot, there are two partitions one is 19.53 GB (7th from bottom) and another one is 11.35 GB (third from bottom).

I tried to read different articles on internet about it but i could not get the proper clarification.

Hence my question here is, if i move the other partitions and try to make unallocated partitions adjacent to combine them as a one partition, will the moving process for other partition deletes the data on the disks or not.

[image: screenshot of GParted]

Comment: Moving partitions doesn't delete data.

Comment: And "unallocated space" is not a partition. It is a space where you can create partitions, or use it to increase an adjacent partition.

Comment: I don't see Ubuntu anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you move a partition, the data is not removed if everything goes well. There is always some risk though. It is recommended to make backups.

Also if you move a partition that is used to boot a system, it is possible that it won't boot, because the system may try to use a fixed sector to boot from.

Generally it is a correct way to organize free space by moving partitions and should be safe enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Note that the user doesn't appear to have Ubuntu on their disk. They've just apparently booted Ubuntu Live to use gparted to do disk maintenance.